# How can I get PowerShell to use the updated PowerShellGet 2.2.5 version instead of 1.0.0.1?

Tags: powershell

Updated PowerShellGet to 2.2.5 but it's still using 1.0.0.1

In PowerShell 5.1, I need to use the newer version of PowerShellGet so I can use the -AllowPrerelease option of Install-Module. I've installed PowerShellGet 2.2.5 using the methods found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/gallery/powershellget/install-powershellget?view=powershellget-2.x) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/gallery/powershellget/update-powershell-51?view=powershellget-2.x), but I still can't use -AllowPrerelease.  How do I get PowerShell to use the newer module?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHLKk.jpg)

- Windows 10 Enterprise 22H2
- I have .NET 4.8 installed.
- I am using TLS 1.2
- I am running 64-bit PowerShell
- Tried Update-Module PowerShellGet -force -allowclobber
- Uninstalled and reinstalled PowerShellGet
- Tried restarting PowerShell.
- Tried Rebooting

Answer (score 1):

If you're really running a 64-bit version of Windows PowerShell (verify with `[Environment]::Is64BitProcess`), `C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` should *not* be an entry in your `$env:PSModulePath`, and the reason that it (a) is and (b) seems to come *before* the 64-bit `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` entry (per your screenshot) is the cause of your problem.

Solution:

- Remove `C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` from the persistent 64-bit definition of your `PSModulePath` environment variable.
- If you also want to run 32-bit sessions, also update the `PowerShellGet` module there.

Comment: Thank you!  I used $env:PSModulePath = "... to reset the variable, removing the x86 path.  All set!

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed a new version of a module but PowerShell is still using an older version of that module, you can have PowerShell use the new version by importing it via the Import-Module command.
In this case to import PowerShellGet version 2.2.5 use the command:

```
Import-Module PowerShellGet -RequiredVersion 2.2.5
```

Comment: It would be great if you can add an exolanation of the solution.